# i want to Not16 bits. but the answer is wrong.Why?

Tags: c#

I want to get 16 bits from Listbox  and Not those bits. but I get wrong answer  can anybody help me what's going wrong?

Input = 1101010101110101
Output = -1101010101110102

the expected result is : 0010101010001010
here is my code.

```
public static long NotInputEqualWhichBit(String str)
{
        long Input = (Int64.Parse(str));
        long notInput = ~Input;

        return notInput;
}
```

and i called this method bellow

```
string listBoxLine = ListBox_content.Items[2].ToString();
long res2 = checkLogic_Class.NotInputEqualWhichBit(listBoxLine);
MessageBox.Show(res2 +"");
```

Comment: We don't know what input you're providing or what value you expect - these should be in the *question*, not in a picture. Please provide a [mcve] - just a simple console app. Note that your picture looks like you're using binary - `Int64.Parse` is going to assume decimal...

Comment: Use `Convert.ToInt64(str, 2)` for binary string to long conversion.

Comment: @Jon Skeet i highlighted the input in Listbox and highlighted the answer in Messagebox

Comment: Please fix the imgur.com link to the screen shot. It brings up a 503 error.

Comment: @Mo0rteza what is the expected output (in message box)?

Comment: At the moment the input is of type `string` and it contains probably a binary representation of a number. So is the string `0010101010001010` what you expect as result? Please tell us what result you expect and of which type it should be.

Comment: There's no need for a screenshot here at all. There's no need for a GUI. As I requested before, please provide a [mcve] - just a console app with hard-coded input and expected output. Please bear in mind that the aim of Stack Overflow is to provide a repository of high quality questions and answers. At the moment, this *isn't* a high quality question. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little vague, so my answer will be too.

You are parsing a binary string as an int64. Basically, you're converting a `11` (string, but to you it is the binary value of three) into an `11` (decimal value of eleven).

If your question is about **how a "2" digit can show up in your result**, then this is your answer: when you convert your input to a `int64`, the conversion assumes that you're using decimal notation, not binary. Therefore, it interprets a different mathematical value.
Decimal notations allow for more than just `0` and `1`, so that's why the 2 shows up.

If that's not your question, continue reading.

In C# (among other languages), the first bit that you find in an integer is called the "signed" bit. If it is 0, your integer is positive. If it is 1, your integer is negative.

Because you are inverting every bit, you are also flipping the signed bit; therefore turning your value into a negative number.

Change the following line:

```
long Input = (Int64.Parse(str));
```

Into the following:

```
ulong Input = (Convert.ToUInt64(str));
```

This is an **unsigned** `long`. Simply put, it does not have a signed bit and therefore cannot turn into a negative number.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important issue is that you want to make certain you have 16 bit and invert these. That is done by typecasting to ushort.

```
ushort i = 5;
Console.WriteLine((ushort)~i);
```